# Do browsers cache php authenticated resources apache

Tags: php, browser-cache, lamp

I am new to running my own server and fairly new to web development. I am trying to design esstialliy a photo album that authenticates pictures resources through a php file. In order to reduce server loading and users data, would a browser cache that? And do I have to do anything special to make the server allow the browser to cache?

```
 <img src="getPicture.php">
```

Comment: yes it would be cached assuming it returns the same headers every time

Comment: Thanks. I will have to look into it more.